# AWS WordPress ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I recently migrated from HostGator to AWS. Everything has worked, including the SSL. This happens on all browsers. Here is what I have setup: (Screenshots attached)

An EC2 instance that's running the WordPress AMI and has an Elastic IP assigned [EC2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgQM4.png)
ACM for both domain.com and www.domain.com, verified by DNS on Route 53 [ACM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lORvu.png)
Target Group with port 80 and HTTP protocol being targeted to the EC2 
instance [Target Group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UO8NI.png)
Load Balancer listening to port 80 and 443 both forwarded to Target Group [Load Balancer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xkp4.png)
Route 53 with the A record using the Load Balancer as an alias [Route 53](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9jyG.png)
CloudFront with domain.com as origin domain name(www.domain.com as CNAME), protocol of "Match Viewer", and connected to the ACM certificate [CloudFront](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NeZK5.png).

What would be causing the error? Where should I start looking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Check URL settings via Administrator Dashboard

[image]

2. or change the URL from wp-config.php

simply add these two lines of code there

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

3. or check deactivating all plugin, anyof plugin maycauing the issue

4. or try using Simple SSL plugin.

Comment: Thank you Earid, the 2nd suggestion along with following the Bitnami documentation here https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/how-to/configure-elb-ssl-aws/ solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and in my case I was able to solve the problem adding this line to `.htaccess`:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase X-FORWARDED-PROTO "^https$" HTTPS
```